# could not connect localhost with cassandra?

Tags: php, cassandra

my cassandra is working well in CLI. and thrift also installed well. i already started apache server and cassandara..but when trying to execute php file that is not executed on browser.it shows the error as:
TException: Error: TSocket: Could not connect to localhost:9160 (Permission denied [13])

and the 12th and 13th line is:
 $socket = new TSocket('localhost', 9160);
  $transport = new TBufferedTransport($socket, 1024, 1024);

i gave 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.even it is not working.

can any one please help me?

Comment: The address is fine, your permissions are not. You should check those, never worked with Cassandra. But you want to make sure that the proper permissions are setup. This can widely vary depending on what OS you are running this on.

Comment: to establish the connection i did this....                              $socket = new TSocket('localhost', 9160);
  $transport = new TBufferedTransport($socket, 1024, 1024);
  $protocol = new TBinaryProtocolAccelerated($transport);
  $client = new CassandraClient($protocol);
  $transport->open();

Comment: and i gave permission to the root folder in the WWW folder by using command chown -R karthibala /var/www/html/test/...but still not working..

Answer (score 1):

hi every one i solve the problem....

selinux is cause for that problem.....

TException: Error: TSocket: Could not connect to localhost:9160 (Permission denied [13])
To resolve it, you need to change an SELinux boolean value (which will automatically persist across reboots). You may also want to restart httpd to reset the proxy worker, although this isn't strictly required.

## setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

Comment: Thank you soooooo much, ive been having issues all day where i could connect from php in shell but it didnt work via apache. this solved my problem. LEGEND!